# Rewriting $\mathscr P(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i)\not\subset\bigcup_{i \in I} \mathscr P(A_i)$ in more fundamental terms.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Working through Velleman's "How to Prove It" and currently having a bit of difficulty with a problem where I'm asked to rewrite this:

$$\mathscr P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)\not\subset\bigcup_{i \in  I} \mathscr P(A_i)$$

. . . using only . . .

$$\land \lor \exists \forall \in \notin \to \iff = \neq$$

Here's what I've come up with so far:

$$ \mathscr P\left( \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \right) \not\subset \bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr P(A_i) $$

The first element I look at here is the 'not a subset' element.

$$
\exists x\,\left( x\in \mathscr P\left( \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \right) \wedge x\notin \bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr P(A_i) \right)
$$

I know being a member of the power set of something is basically being a subset of that thing.

$$\exists x \left( \left(\forall y(y \in x \to \exists i \in I(y \in A_i)\right) \land x \notin \bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr P(A_i)\right)$$

This next part is where I feel like I'm making some kind of mistake. I feel like I've got something wrong about the union of a power set here.

$$\exists x(\forall y(y \in x \to \exists i \in I(y \in A_i)) \land \lnot \exists i \in I(\forall y(y \in x \to y \in A_i)))$$

If $x$ is the member of a union of some indexed family of sets, then there exists some some index $i$ in the index set $I$ such that $x$ is a member of the set $A_i$. So if the set it's a member of is the $\mathscr P(A_i)$ . . . I just substitute the definition of membership in a power set in where I'd otherwise state the set?

I feel like I'm making a really silly mistake in my reasoning, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: \cup_i{_\in}{_I} is not the right way to code $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}$.  There shouldn't be three separate subscripts like that, but just one: \bigcup_{i\in I}. It is conventional to use $\cup$ in things like $A\cup B$ or $A_1\cup \cdots \cup A_n$ and $\bigcup$ in things like $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$. The latter, when in an inline setting rather than a displayed setting, appears as $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$.  The repetition of subscripts where there should be just one subscript is not only makes things needlessly complicated but can cause mis-formatting in some cases. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct, though not the first translation that I’d have come up with. I’d work a bit informally first. Suppose that

$$x\in\wp\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I}\wp(A_i)\;;$$

then $x\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, but for each $i\in I$ we have $x\nsubseteq A_i$. The first of these says that

$$\forall y\in x\,\exists i\in I(y\in A_i)\;;$$

the second says that

$$\forall i\in I\,\exists y\in x(y\notin A_i)\;.$$

Putting the pieces together:

$$\exists x\Big(\big(\forall y\in x\,\exists i\in I(y\in A_i)\big)\land\big(\forall i\in I\,\exists y\in x(y\notin A_i)\big)\Big)\;.$$

As you can see, it’s very similar; it just expresses the second part a bit differently by pushing the negation inside the quantifiers. You can get rid of the bounded universal quantifiers with implications, just as you did in your version. You can also get rid of the bounded existential quantifiers using conjunctions. I’ll not write out the whole thing, but for example the first clause can be expanded to

$$\forall y\big(y\in x\to\exists i(i\in I\land y\in A_i)\big)\;.$$

Comment: This is a very clear and helpful explanation. I'm pretty sure I understand it now, and I'll try applying the approach you've shown here to the next set of similar problems in the book. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user242007: You’re very welcome; I’m glad that it helped!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : ok, So you've made it clear that you have an emphatic preference for $\wp(A)$ rather than $\mathscr P(A)$.  Is there a reason for that? (To me the former looks like a lower-case letter, whereas I've always seen something that looks like a capital used for that.) $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael: Yes. You won’t consider it a *good* reason, I suspect, but it is a reason. In my handwriting I distinguish the power set script P from the script P that I would use to designate a family of sets, for instance, and it just happens that $\wp$ and $\mathscr{P}$ are fairly decent matches for my handwritten symbols. The former definitely does not look lower-case to me.

Answer (score 1):

Set $B=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, for the moment. You want to state that there exists $x\subset B$ such that $x\notin\mathcal{P}(A_i)$, for all $i\in I$, that is, $x\not\subset A_i$, for all $i\in I$.

The condition $x\not\subset A_i$ can be expressed by
$$
\exists y(y\in A_i\land y\notin x)
$$

Applying the universal quantifier:
$$
\forall i(i\in I\to(\exists y(y\in A_i\land y\notin x))
$$
Thus the statement is
$$
\exists x(x\subset B\land\forall i(i\in I\to(\exists y(y\in A_i\land y\notin x)))
$$
Now we want to translate $x\subset B$: for any $z\in x$, there must exist $j\in I$ with $z\in A_j$; so
$$
\forall z(z\in x\to\exists j(j\in I\land z\in A_j))
$$
Finally, the formula should be
$$
\exists x((\forall z(z\in x\to\exists j(j\in I\land z\in A_j)))\land\forall i(i\in I\to(\exists y(y\in A_i\land y\notin x)))
$$